# Query builder all data loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to show only the people the user is messaging, but all users are showing. How can i fix this?

SQL TABLE PHOTO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pOPa.png

```
 public static function otherUserData($user_id)

  {

    $value = DB::table('users')

    ->select(['*', DB::raw('MAX(conver_date) AS lastConver')])

    ->leftJoin('conversation', function ($join) use ($user_id) {

        $join->on('conversation.conver_seller_id', '=', 'users.id')

            ->on('conversation.conver_user_id', '=', DB::raw($user_id))

            ->orOn('conversation.conver_seller_id', '=', DB::raw($user_id))

            ->on('conversation.conver_user_id', '=', 'users.id'); 

    })

    ->where('user_type', '!=', 'admin')

    ->where('id', '!=', $user_id)

    ->where('drop_status', '=', 'no')

    ->orderBy('lastConver', 'desc')

    ->groupBy('id')

    ->get(); 



return $value;

  }
```

I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: change `leftJoin` to just `join`